# Access phone contacts to see who already has an account

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a feature in my app, where users can see a contact list of which contacts (based on mobile number) already has an account on our app.

This feature can be found in all social media and banking apps.

Can someone guide on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-contacts to get all the contact details, then pass this array to your backend service to find the accounts with the phone number, then you can display them.